# Where are the places the PROMPT_COMMAND variable could be set?

Tags: environment-variables, bashrc, profile

I installed [drush](http://docs.drush.org/en/master/install/) and as part of the installation it makes some changes to the PROMPT

```
...
# Optional. Enrich the bash startup file with completion and aliases.
drush init
...
```

Whenever I execute an command at the prompt I get the message:

```
bash: __drush_ps1: command not found
```

The `env` command displays `PROMPT_COMMAND` as

```
PROMPT_COMMAND=__git_ps1 "\u@\h \w" "$(__drush_ps1 "[%s]") \\\$ "
```

I think somewhere at the global level the PROMPT_COMMAND variable is set to that value but I can't locate it in any of the global environment variables and profile scripts.

Because `drush` was installed as `root` commands executed as `root` don't produce that error message. `root` has a `.drush` directory with some `drush` scripts.

UPDATE: After inquiring from the drupal forum https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/198484/where-does-the-drush-installtation-command-set-the-prompt-command-variable/198487 I know which of the `drush` installation commands create that setting. **What I can't find is which of the Linux bash and environment files execute that setting at logon time**. Any new account I create produces that error when I execute a command at the shell, so the setting must be at a global level. One of the files here or in the related directories `/etc/{bash.bashrc,bash_completion, bash_completion.d,environment}` must have the command that sets the `PROMPT_COMMAND` variable at logon time, but I can't find it.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4):

The list of files that bash loads during startup is documented in the manual. There's `~/.bash_profile`, `~/.profile`, `~/.bash_login` and `/etc/profile` for a login shell, and `~/.bashrc` (and `/etc/bash.bashrc` or similar on some systems) for an interactive shell.

It's common for these files to include other files, and there's no general rule that would give you an exhaustive list of where to look.

Run `bash -ix </dev/null 2>trace` (or `bash -lx </dev/null 2>/trace` if you want to start a login shell). This writes a trace of all the commands that bash executes to the `trace` file. Search for `PROMPT_COMMAND` in that trace, and search a `source` or `.` command before it to find where it was set. It's possible that `PROMPT_COMMAND` is set in a function that's defined in one file and executed in another file, in which case you may need to explore the trace further.